# How to call an event?

Tags: vb.net, scintilla

How can I call a `CharAdded` event when my `scintilla Text window` has text added. I have tried adding this:

```
  Private Sub Scintilla_CharAdded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ScintillaNet.CharAddedEventArgs) Handles Scintilla1.CharAdded
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), Scintilla).AutoComplete.Show()
    End Sub
```

But it only calls when the Scintilla window is implemented on my form in the design file. However I needed to work when I implement it like this:

```
Dim TextInput As New Scintilla
```

So is it possible to call this event when it is not placed directly in my designer?

Thanks.

Comment: when the user adds text, the event is raised, and code inside the event can be called.  your code should not call events, or you will write more and more code to discern real events and events you cause. What is that code trying to do? OTOH, code can exist outside events.  Just write a procedure to do what you want and call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `Handles` keyword, you can do so by defining your `TextInput` as a field of your form (a variable at the form-level, outside of any method).  You then need to add the `WithEvents` modifier to the variable declaration, like this:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Private WithEvents TextInput As New Scintilla

    Private Sub Scintilla_CharAdded(sender As Object, e As ScintillaNet.CharAddedEventArgs) Handles TextInput.CharAdded
        ' ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you can't define it as a field of your form, then you won't be able to use the `Handles` keyword.  In that case, you'd need to resort to using the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` commands to register your event handler with the object.